# inner and outer join together in query, possible

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, outer-join

i am trying to implement inner and outer join in single query, i am not sure if i am doing the right way or wrong way, as i am not very good with queries.

So here it goes.

I have these following tables.

```
hrs_residentials
hrs_residential_utilities
hrs_utilities
hrs_utility_type
```

**hrs_residentials**:

```
ResID,   ResType,  ResNo  -    -    -  
1          2        001   -    -    -
```

**hrs_residential_utilities**:

```
RUID, UtilityID, ResID, -   -    -    - 
NULL    NULL      NULL
```

**hrs_utilities**:

```
UtilityID, UtilityTypeID, Number, ConsumerNumber,  -,   -,   -
 NULL         NULL          NULL        NULL
```

**hrs_utility_type**:

```
UTID, UName, UDescription
1     PESCO   PESCO Electric Meter
2     SNGPL   Sui Northen Gas Pipe Lines
```

So i want to show in datatables the data, but what i want that data should show in table for hrs_residentials table, dosent matter if hrs_residential_utilities have data or not. 
So i went for Left outer join and i got the result i wanted.

But after that when i tried to do inner for `hrs_residential_utilities` with `hrs_utilities`, i stopped getting results for `hrs_residentials` as well. As if we see `hrs_residential` do have the data inside table. I dont want inner join with `hrs_residentials`, i want to have inner join between `hrs_residential_utilities` and `hrs_utilities`.

Is it possible, or i am following the wrong approach here? Sorry i am not good. What will the Proper Query if anyone can help me with it.

This is the Query i have tried so far.

```
SELECT R.`ResID`,R.`ResNo`
FROM `hrs_residentials` R
LEFT OUTER JOIN `hrs_residential_utilities` RU
ON R.`ResID` = RU.ResID
INNER JOIN `hrs_utilities` U
ON RU.`UtilityID` = U.`UtilityID`
WHERE 1=1;
```

I stopped Getting Results from the `hrs_residential`s table After the Inner Join, but i am making Inner join between other two tables.

Comment: Just use another left join: replace `INNER JOIN `hrs_utilities` U` with `LEFT JOIN `hrs_utilities` U`

Comment: @EugenRieck
But will this be the outer join then?? i mean if i do LEFT JOIN only then, will this be INNER or OUTER Join?

Comment: Hi this is possible. an inner join will only return results if the id on which you're joining exists in both tables. I'd query up until the inner join and see the returned values of RU.UtilityID then check if they match anything in the hrs_utilities table

Comment: In MySQL `LEFT JOIN` == `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Rule of thumb: All joins to an outer join must be outer joins.

Comment: @EugenRieck
Yes, i know that would work, if i had to use all outer joins i would have dont that already.
But, Sir, i am looking for possibility to have both inner join and outer join work together in a single query?

Comment: @Oliverb
Sir, can you explain it in the code. i am keep loosing you after your first line.
Sorry for my bad english thou.

Answer (score 0):

Try a subquery like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `hrs_residentials` R
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
SELECT * FROM
`hrs_residential_utilities` RU
INNER JOIN `hrs_utilities` U
ON RU.`UtilityID` = U.`UtilityID`
) AS subqyr
ON R.`ResID` = subqyr.`ResID`
```

Comment: -1 Performance killer (The subquery will be materialized to disk, if it reaches a non-trivial size)

Comment: Maybe, I think performance killer is a bit strong. I've seen test where it was faster with smaller datasets. I think it's more readable this way. I thought if Sizzling Code was in a situation where this sort issue are not trivial, he wouldn't have asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

run this query and view the results

SELECT R.`ResID`,R.`ResNo`
FROM `hrs_residentials` R
LEFT OUTER JOIN `hrs_residential_utilities` RU
ON R.`ResID` = RU.ResID

then run this query and view the results:

```
SELECT * FROM hrs_utilities
```

I suspect what you will find is that the RU.utilities ID does not match anything in the hrs_utilities.

Your query itself should return everything in hrs_residentials and join on any matching data from hrs_residential_utilities this may or may not return RU.ResID as null depending on whether it can match.

It then filters on whether RU.UtilityId matches with anything in the hrs_utilities table, this won't match on null items.

Thanks. 
oliver